# Ana B'Koach authorship and the 42 letter name of Hashem

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, shemos-sacred-names, authorship, tannaim

In my Artscroll siddur it tells me that the hymn Ana B'Koach was written by the tanna, Rebbi Nechunia ben HaKana and that the first letter of each word can be used to form the 42 letter name of Hashem. I would like to know what the source for either of these claims, authorship and letters spelling out the shem Hashem, is.

Comment: It is not the 42 letter name of Hashem, it correspondes to the 42 letter name. (Arizal says this)

Comment: @HachamGabriel, what does that mean?

Comment: The Rashe Tevot of every word corresponds to the Shem Mem Bet,

Comment: @HachamGabriel, that is what the question says... what am I not understanding?

Comment: @Daniel I understand from what you wrote that you think that the Rashe Tevot are actually the Shem Mem Bet while in reality they only represent the Shem Mem Bet.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, care to explain what you mean by that? How do they represent it?

Comment: @Daniel those letters aren't actually the Mem Bet. Simple as that. They just are a representation.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, do you mean to say that there are 42 roshe teivot as a numerical correspondance to the 42 letter name? If that is the case, why don't we say that the words correspond to the name rather than the first letters?

Comment: @Daniel not sure.

Comment: The acronym shows up in Tikun Hazohar 4.

Comment: @HachamGabriel 1)how do you know those aren't the exact 42 letters? 2)if they aren't then what is the purpose of that song?

Answer (score 2):

from what i understand kabalists attribute the piyut to R' Nechunia ben HaKana, but usually it is dated to the 12th-13th century  by "Chassidei Ashkenaz" (who also composed "anim zemirot")

Comment: A nice summary of wikipedia http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%97